# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:19.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am trying to add Firebase Analytics and I am constantly getting the follow errors when trying to sync the Gradle project:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:19.0.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:19.0.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:19.0.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:19.0.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:19.0.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:19.0.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:19.0.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:19.0.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:19.0.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

This is the implementation that I am using:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
```

and

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

I have read various posts but non seem to resolve this issue.

For some reason, I am seeing that is trying to resolve for version **19.0.0** when I am explicitly telling it to use version **17.2.1**.

This is a snippet of the build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' version '0.8.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
    flavorDimensions "default"


    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

}

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.11.4'

    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids:casty:1.0.8'
    implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:4.3.0'
}
```

And project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()


    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:12.0.1"
    }
}

subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->

            if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
                    && details.requested.name.contains('play-services-cast')) {
                details.useVersion "12.0.1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas of what could be causing this conflict?

Comment: you probably have another library using 19.0.0

Comment: Please edit the question to show the *entire, minimal build.gradle* where you see this behavior. Also read this for tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have edited the questions including the basic build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

try this
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please explain *why* OP shall use version `17.2.2`.